# C# Removing elements and reorder

Tags: c#

I have one main collection

```
List<int> main = Enumerable.Range(0,11).ToList();
```

And I have 3 lists:

```
List<int> a = new List<int>{main[0],main[1],main[5],main[3]}; //I delete this list with all its items from the main
List<int> b = new List<int>{main[2],main[6],main[7]};
List<int> c = new List<int>{main[8],main[9],main[4],main[11],main[10]};
```

Now I want to **remove** from **main** list 0, 1, 5, 3 items and I delete **a** list totally, consequently I would like to update  **b c** ones.

Meaning they will become:

```
List<int> main = new List<int> {0,1,2,4,5,6,7};

List<int> b = new List<int>{main[0],main[2],main[3]};
List<int> c = new List<int>{main[4],main[5],main[1],main[7],main[6]};
```

Do I need some sort of mapping, maybe somebody else have encountered similar issue before?

Maybe this screenshot demonstrates what I want to do better:
After this I have to update the b and c collections

[image]

Comment: Do you want `b` and `c` to automatically update when you modify `main`? If so you should make them of type `Func<List<T>>` rather than `List<T>`.  You can remove elements of `a` from `main` by doing `main = main.Except(a).ToList()`, but then it will be a whole new `List`. If you want to preserve the original instance, you will need to create a method that loops over the indices from `Count - 1` to `0` and removes them if they are in `a`.

Comment: Could you provide a complete example with your code which removes items? I don't get how after deleting items 0, 1, 5, 3, your main list would contain numbers 0,1,2,4,5,6,7

Comment: I mainly remove list a, and the b with c has to be updated accordingly.

Comment: @Meta-Knight Sorry it was a typing mistake. Basically a b c lists relies on one collection (which is consequent number from 0 to total number of items). What I would like to do is to remove a list, and that b c would be updated accordingly. None of a b c have any sharing integers.

Comment: @JamesFaix What difference would it make if he assigns a new list (using `Except`) or removes them from the original instance (using `Remove`)?

Comment: @Petras What do you mean *"b and c would be updated accordingly"*? They don't change at all when the members of `a` are removed from `main`, do they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what you want to do, but you can achieve similar thing using LINQ lazy evaluation. You cannot do what you want to do with hard-coded indices. You need to use filters and LINQ methods.

```
List<int> main = Enumerable.Range(0,11).ToList();

List<int> a = new List<int>{ 1, 5, 3, 0, 7};
IEnumerable<int> b = main.Where(i => i % 2 == 0);
IEnumerable<int> c = main.Where(i => i % 2 == 1);

foreach (var i in b)
{
    Console.Write(i + ","); // 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10
}
Console.WriteLine();

foreach (var i in c)
{
    Console.Write(i + ","); // 1, 3, 5, 7, 9
}
Console.WriteLine();


foreach (var i in a)
{
    main.Remove(i);
}

foreach (var i in b)
{
    Console.Write(i + ","); // 2, 4, 6, 8, 10
}
Console.WriteLine();

foreach (var i in c)
{
    Console.Write(i + ","); // 9
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Linq`'s `Except` function.

```
main = main.Except(a).ToList();
```